# AngularJS Directives and the link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Could someone explain why when I try to change the background colour of my custom directive to red using this piece of code it doesn't work.

```
app.directive('isolateDir', [function(){

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        scope: { stockData: "="},
        link: function(scope, element, attr){
            scope.changeColour = function(){
                element[0].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            };
        }
    }
}]);
```

And yet when I use this piece it does.

```
app.directive('isolateDir', [function(){

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        scope: { stockData: "="},
        link: function(scope, element, attr){
            scope.changeColour = function(){
                element.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            };
        }
    }
}]);
```

I thought the element parameter in the link function referenced that instance of the directive.

Comment: sure you don't have those backwards? `element` is an `angular.element` object ( is jQuery if jQuery.js included) not a dom element.

Comment: Not sure what your end goal is, but if you are trying to change styles I would consider using `ng-class` and `css` to toggle styles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because element is the jqLite-wrapped element that this directive matches. The DOM element it self is the element[0].

You can find more information here:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

```
Take a look at this plunker that output in console the wrapped element and the DOM element:
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Kcu7nHVzacbsSDiXSt6U?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Angular return a jQlite object. So, like `jQuery`, to select current html element you need to use `element[0]`.

Please refer this [article](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/d3-on-angular.html).

Answer (score 1):

the above piece of code will work with

```
element[0].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

element here in directive is a jqLite wrapped directive element, in order to change the style you can use jqLite functions. if not we can query from array of elements in jqlite object as 'element[0]', in which we get the core dom object to set the style in which we did as above.